# Does WebGLU have all of WebGL's functions?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

"[WebGLU](https://github.com/OneGeek/WebGLU) is both a set of low-level utilities and a high-level engine for developing WebGL based applications ... by exposing the raw GL object and also many lower-level functions for working with it and the WebGL API."

Does this mean that WebGLU has the same functions as WebGL (plus more)? Looking at the code, I see for example that WebGL's clearColor is used by WebGLU like so:

```
$W.GL.clearColor(R, G, B, A);
```

So, if there is a WebGL function foo() that I want to use, can I use it via WebGLU by just doing

```
$W.GL.foo()
```

or something similar? Is that how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source file, `$W.GL` is:

```
/** The raw WebGL object for low level work. */
```

As such, yes. `$W.GL` will contain all the same functions as a standard WebGL context because it *is* a WebGL context.